# C++ | Only reference variable works in function template

Tags: c++, function, templates

While using function tempelate, I am only able to use reference variables as function parameters.

Below program (to find minimum between two numbers) works fine.

```
//Program to calculate minimum among two numbers
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class ttype>
//Using reference variables 
//as function parameters
ttype min(ttype& a, ttype& b)
{
    ttype res = a;
    if (b < a)
        res = b;
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 10; 
    int mini = min(a, b); 
    cout << "Minimum is: " << mini << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I change the function as below:

```
template <class ttype>
//Using normal variables 
//as function parameters
ttype min(ttype a, ttype b)
{
    ttype res = a;
    if (b < a)
        res = b;
    return res;
}
```

I get compile error.

Should we only use reference variables while using function template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` conflicts with `std::min` since you are `using namespace std;`

You can do the following to fix it, which explicitly says to use the `min` that is outside all namespaces:

```
int mini = ::min(a, b);
```

Alternatively, get rid of the `using` and it works.

Both of these solutions work for me on gcc, with the `&` and without it.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the min clashes with the std::min. Either use a different name for your function, or do not use "using namespace std", or put your function in a different namespace, or use this:

```
int mini = ::min(a, b);
```